# Xamarin DependencyService

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I followed other questions in stack overflow and made sure my register in the assembly registers the android implementation and not the base interface and also that all classes are public. Anyhow I still get the `System.MissingMethodException: 'Default constructor not found for type Foodies.VisualEffects.IStatusBarColor'`message.

I declare my base interface in the common project at Foodies/Views/VisualEffects/iStatusBarColor.cs, like this:

```
namespace Foodies.Views.VisualEffects
{
    public interface IStatusBarColor
    {
        void MakeMe(string color);
    }
}
```

Then in my android project I add StatusBarColor_Android, looking like:

```
using Android.OS;
using Foodies.Droid;
using Foodies.Views.VisualEffects;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(StatusBarColor_Android))]

namespace Foodies.Droid
{ 
    public class StatusBarColor_Android : IStatusBarColor
    {
        public void MakeMe(string color)
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
            {
                var c = MainActivity.context as FormsAppCompatActivity;
                c?.RunOnUiThread(() => c.Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(color)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and them from my main page I call:

```
 var dp = DependencyService.Get<IStatusBarColor>();
                dp?.MakeMe(Color.Blue.ToHex());
```

And there, i the DependencyService.Get I do get the System.MissingMethodException: 'Default constructor not found for type Foodies.VisualEffects.IStatusBarColor

This is my android project settings
[image: android project settings]

Im new to Xamarin, could someone help me finding the error ??

Comment: What is your linking behaviour set to?

Comment: con guide me on how to check it? I started a Master-detail project in Xamarin in VS 2019 and did not change anything

Comment: Did you solved your issue?

Comment: @MihailDuchev I found the linking behavior and added a picture. This is what you meant? (was like this, keeps not working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out in addition to all of this, in the MainActivity, in the `OnCreate` I had

```
DependencyService.Register<IStatusBarColor>();
```

Just remove this sentence and it works nice.

Additionally, changing the registered class too StatusBarColor_Android, and not the base interface also works. I found it just cleaner to remove the whole thing and let the [assembly...] do the job

Comment: It's strange that i add the line in OnCreat method, it still work .Do you test in a new empty project ?

Comment: If I register the proper class, not the interface it works. But I had the interface registered here (as you do in your example)

Comment: Yes,this is because the wrong registration method, but it is not obvious in your question.I give an update to the answer above.

Comment: it forced me to wait 24h to do so  :) 1h more to be waited and I do it

Comment: Better to remove this sentence. It works sometimes and it doesn't. When it doesn't work, it creates the "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. I found this error by using Try-Catch for my OnCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

The `namespace` in the code above is confusing，as you said

> I declare my base interface in the common project at
>   Foodies/Views/iStatusBarColor.cs

Normally if you don't customize namepace, it should be：

```
namespace Foodies.Views
{
   public interface IStatusBarColor
   {
      void MakeMe(string color);
   }
}
```

and in you Android project,why you have two different reference `using Foodies.Droid;` and `using Foodies.VisualEffects.Droid;`,and you didn't reference the namepace `Foodies.Views` when you implement `IStatusBarColor`

Try to change like :

```
using Foodies.Droid;
using Foodies.Views;
using Android.OS;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(StatusBarColor_Android))]

namespace Foodies.Droid
{ 
  public class StatusBarColor_Android : IStatusBarColor
   {
      public void MakeMe(string color)
      {
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
        {
            var c = MainActivity.context as FormsAppCompatActivity;
            c?.RunOnUiThread(() => c.Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(color)));
        }
      }
   }
}
```

**Update** :
The cause of this problem is the wrong registration method.There are two ways to register.

1.Register in your implementation class directly，like the codes above
using `[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(StatusBarColor_Android))]`

2.call `DependencyService.Register<StatusBarColor_Android >();` in your MainActivity `OnCreate` method.(**Note**:here you should use the class name which you implement the interface,not the name of interface).

Comment: Nop. nothing changed. The Namespace was already correct (it did compile). Can you tell me where to change the link behavior ?

Comment: @javirs right click your Android project,then properties > Android options >  Linking > select None.

Comment: I edited my OP to include a print on it. Looks Ok? Still not working

Comment: @javirs The codes above are correctly now.It's weird. Do you have any other classes that extends this interface? If no,you could try to create a new empty project,then use above codes,and have a try.

Comment: ill give it a try, thanks (no other clases, is just the first time I do it and was copying from a tutorial step by step :( )

Comment: BTW I removed my IOs project since I won't be releasing for ios. I just removed the project from the Solution explorer.. Could be related ??

Comment: @javirs It shouldn't matter (If there is a relationship that may be deleted not completely),so  you could create an android-only project.

Comment: I my .. I found my error. From another tutorial I had : `DependencyService.Register<IStatusBarColor>();` in the `OnCreate` of the MainActivity Removing this did the trick ..